# Turning a SOAP response into an STD object with PHP

Tags: php, soap, wsdl, stdclass

I am learning about SOAP for a project and I now understand the basics of it. Can't believe I've never tried using this before. It's great. But anyway, to my problem.

I have managed to successfully print the response of my request to the web browser but I cannot seem to convert this response into an STD object.

I've been following a tutorial and adapting it to a different WDSL file to fully understand what I'm doing.

This is my PHP file.

```
<?

//////////////////////////////////////
//
//  ABOUT:      This file will send a request to the WSDL file and return a result in the browser window
//  AUTHOR:     Brad Bird
//  DATE:       07/02/2013
//
//////////////////////////////////////

// Setup the SOAP Client options
$wsdl = "http://www.mobilefish.com/services/web_service/countries.php?wsdl";
$options = array(
    "trace" => 1,
    "exception" => 0
);

// Creates new instance of the SOAP Client
$client = new SoapClient($wsdl, $options);

// Return a set of information using one function
$countryCode = "af";
$values = $client->countryInfoByIana($countryCode);

// Prints the details of the request and response to the browser
print "<h2>SOAP Details</h2>";
print "<pre>";
print "<h3>Request</h3> " . htmlspecialchars($client->__getLastRequest()) . "<br />";
print "<h3>Response</h3> " . htmlspecialchars($client->__getLastResponse());
print "</pre>";

// Prints the request in XML format
$xml = $values->countryInfoByIanaResponse;

print "<h2>stdClass Object</h2>";
print "<pre>";
print_r($xml);
print "</pre>";
```

And this WSDL file I'm trying to get request from is here.
http://www.mobilefish.com/services/web_service/countries.php?wsdl

For some reason the STD Object section is showing nothing. Any ideas?

Comment: `print_r($values);` what happens?

Comment: I'm on my mobile at the moment. But I did try that and it didn't produce the std object.

Comment: +1 for copy/paste ready code. Maybe shorten it a little next time - thee who asks the question is likely the author.

Comment: if `print_r($values);` produced nothing then  `$client->countryInfoByIana($countryCode);` is returning nothing.

Comment: @ExternalUse Sorry about that, I could have shortened it a little before posting it on here! I have selected my chosen answer now :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, $xml is not an object of stdClass, but `null`. `$values` however is. `$values->countryInfoByIanaResponse` does not exist. All you have in $values is

```
: object(stdClass) = 
  ianacode: string = "af"
  countryname: string = "Afghanistan"
  latitude: double = 33.93911
  longitude: double = 67.709953
```

Not sure what exactly what you are trying to do - maybe call a method on the $client rather than on your result?
Also, check the PHP manual on error_reporting, you would then have stumbled across this Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$countryInfoByIanaResponse in the print_r line.

Comment: Sorry I'm an idiot. $values didn't work before but I probably changed something in the previous code since I lasted tested it. That is exactly what I needed!